# Google Apps Script: Unable to send emails using createEvent()

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have the following code and attendees are **not able to receive emails** about the event. Though the event is reflecting in their calendar.

```
    var options = {  
     description: description,
     location: location,
     guests: email_address,
     sendInvites: true
   }
   var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).createEvent(title,
                start_datetime, end_datetime,
                options);
```

I have added oauthScopes to appsscript.json as well.

```
 "oauthScopes": [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
   "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"
 ]
```

It seems like an authorization issue but not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. In the options, "Guests" has a value of the variable called "email_address". Would you please include the code for creating this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually add any scopes while running the script from the browser editor.

Your code worked perfectly for me :) I added a few variables to complete it but it worked just fine -

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = 'self@gmail.com'; // if using your own or default calendar ID
  var description = 'test desc';

  // ref link - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#advanced-parameters_4  
  var email_address = 'contact1@gmail.com, contact2@gmail.com';
  // comma separated guest list 

  var title = 'test title';
  var start_datetime = new Date();
  var end_datetime = new Date();
  var options = {  
    description: description,
    guests: email_address,
    sendInvites: true
  }
  var event = CalendarApp
  .getCalendarById(calendarId)
  .createEvent(title, start_datetime, end_datetime, options);
}
```

My default manifest file looks like this -

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

No additional scopes seem to have been added. However, when I view my **File > Project properties > Scope**, only a single scope seem to have been added by the script -

```
OAuth Scope required by script:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Hope this helps.

Edit note: Forgot to add -

**Email notifications are being received as well**

Comment: Thanks for confirming Sourabh. I got the issue, I was creating events for past date, for that email invites will not be sent. :)

Comment: Ah! I see. Sorry, I had not considered that as a scenario but makes sense. Thanks for letting know.